# how to enable multi tabs in ionic for firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make an application that will have access to data offline. But it doesn't seem to work the way I want. If I close and open the application without a network, my cache is not displayed in the application. If I open it online and then turn off the network, the weight works. I suspect that the problem is that when you open the application, the tab changes and the cache does not adjust to it, below is my firebase config:

```
const firestoreSettings = {
  cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
  experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
  experimentalForceOwningTab: true,
  persistence: persistentLocalCache,
  synchronizeTabs: true
};

const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const db = initializeFirestore(app, firestoreSettings);
```

I added cache settings but that didn't help either.

```
const persistentLocalCache = {
  experimentalTabSynchronization: true,
  PersistentMultipleTab: true
};

const firestoreSettings = {
  cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
  experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
  experimentalForceOwningTab: true,
  persistence: persistentLocalCache,
  synchronizeTabs: true
};

const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const db = initializeFirestore(app, firestoreSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const persistentLocalCache = {
  experimentalTabSynchronization: true,
  PersistentMultipleTab: true
};

const firestoreSettings = {
  cacheSizeBytes: CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
  experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
  experimentalForceOwningTab: false, //<-- pass it to false
  persistence: persistentLocalCache,
  synchronizeTabs: true
};

const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
const db = initializeFirestore(app, firestoreSettings);
```

also keep in mind that it uses

> Whether to force enable persistence for the client. This cannot be
> used with synchronizeTabs:true and is primarily intended for use with
> Web Workers. Setting this to true will enable persistence, but cause
> other tabs using persistence to fail.

> To enable this mode, synchronizeTabs:true needs to be set globally in
> all active tabs. If omitted or set to 'false', enablePersistence()
> will fail in all but the first tab.

read [PersistenceSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.PersistenceSettings)

> According to the API Reference docs for enableIndexedDbPersistence,
> the property is now called forceOwnership (not
> experimentalForceOwningTab).

also read
[firestore-persistence-web-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72424417/firestore-persistence-web-issue)

try this and let me know any